# Solve the dress problem

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Background

Peter's Father, the Teacher of a dance-club, asks Peter a question:
Given are two [natural numbers (\$\mathbb{N}\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) \$x\$ and \$y\$).

\$x\$ is the number of the garment types (e.g. shorts, shirts\$\dots\$) we have

\$y\$ is number of colors (e.g. green, blue, \$\dots\$) of each garment we have.

In the dance class, every one should be in a unique dress.

## Example:

[image: not equals to]
But:

[image: equals to]

Now tell me:
For every given \$x\$ and \$y\$, what is the maximum number of people who an visit our class?

Can you help Peter?

## Challenge

The input should be two natural numbers (\$\forall  x,y\in\mathbb{N}\$) separated by a comma`,`.
The input can also be your languages equivalent for a list which has two elements.

The Output should be an Integer, the maximum number of people who can visit the dance-class.

## Test cases

```
In:1,0
Out:0

In:0,0
Out:0

In:[2,2]
Out:4

In:3,2
Out:9
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins

Comment: Or, judging from the images, there are x pieces of clothing, each can be one of y colours. This would be x^y, right?

Comment: @ovs No example 2, 3 is not 2^3 which is 8. There are 9 possiblitys: 12,21,13,31,23,32,11,22,33

Comment: @math ovs just made a typo, the answer is clearly just y^x, with 0^0=0. IMO this is a poor challenge that should have been tested in the Sandbox.

Comment: For the last test case I only get 8 possibilities: 111, 112, 121, 122, 211, 212, 221, 222.

Comment: To look at it another way, it's really just a problem of figuring out MAXINT of a certain length in a certain base.  The length is the number of garments, the base is the number of colors.

Comment: Since [`0^0` is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero), it might have been better without zero in the input. (Also the term "natural number" is ambiguous in whether it includes 0 or not. One should use "positive integer" or "non-negative integer" instead.)

Comment: While I agree with @Bubbler about 0^0 being undefined, what really doesn't make sense here to me is an input of #,0 or 0,#.  If you have 0 items, there are no colors to be had.  If you have no colors, then your items are invisible, so they might as well not exist.

Comment: @Bubbler While I agree that it might be better to not have 0 as input, I don't understand your point of `0^0` being undefined. First of all, the challenge doesn't ask you to calculate `0^0`. Secondly, "no agreed upon value" in the mathematical sense is very different from being undefined in computer languages. The article you link to ends with a ranges of computer language examples where `0^0` *is* defined (usually as 1). And that list is far from complete.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 20 bytes

```perl
/,/;$_=$`*$'&&$'**$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fR99aJd5WJUFLRV1NTUVdS0sl4f9/Yx2jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Comment: @See my comment to ovs. eg.v2,3 is not 2^3.

Comment: Fixed it.  Had the variables reversed.

Comment: Shouldn't `2,3` and `3,2` yield the same result?

Comment: No.  With 2 garments and 3 colors, you get 9 options: `aa`,
`ab`,
`ac`,
`ba`,
`bb`,
`bc`,
`ca`,
`cb`,
`cc`.  With 3 garments and 2 colors, you get 8 options:
`aaa`,
`aab`,
`aba`,
`abb`,
`baa`,
`bab`,
`bba`,
`bbb`

Answer (score 2):

Both answers don't work for 0-inputs, I'm waiting for it to be clarified.

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

Takes input as `colors, garment types`

```
Lπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@d8w////43@GwMA)

### Explanation

```
Inputs: 2, 3

 π  (x, y) 1..x 's cartesian power by y.
           [1, 2] -> [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[2,2],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2],[3,3]]
L   (x) Length of x.
           -> 9
    Implicit output
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Takes input as the specified format.

```
и<²β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wg6bQ5vObfr/34jLGAA)

### Explanation

````
Example inputs: 2, 3

и    Repeat: ["3", "3"]
 <   Decrement: [2, 2]
  ²β From base (second input): 9
```
````

Comment: Porting your Husk answer to 05AB1E is an alternative 4-byter by taking the input in reverse order: `L²ãg`. I like your current 05AB1E more, though. :)